# Closure memory leak patterns in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, memory-leaks, closures

Which of following JavaScript snippets will leak memory?

snippet #1:

```
function foo(obj)
{
    var obj2 = {};
    $('#something').click(function() { alert(obj.id); } );
}
```

snippet #2:

```
function foo(obj)
{
    var obj2 = {}
    $('#something').click(function() { alert('obj was not used.'); } );
}
```

snippet #3:

```
function foo(obj)
{
    var obj2= {id: 1}
    bar(function() { alert(obj2.id); } );
}

function bar(func)
{
    var obj3 = {};
    func();
}
```

and which variables won't be collected by Garbage Collector?
How to fix leaks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As given, none of those will create memory leaks.

Leaks are held by not releasing memory -- everything there gets released.

By the way, none of the code you are showing uses closures.

Now, here are a handful of ways that "leaks" can be created.

```
// Simple leak -- an array that never lets go of memory
var arrayThatNeverShrinks = [];
function doleak() {
  var s = "1234567890";
  arrayThatNeverShrinks.push(s);
  window.setTimeout(doleak, 500);
}
//start if off
doleak();


// This function leaks because bigVar is used -- and kept -- 
// inside of the anonymous function inside.
    //Another leak, using closures
    var leakingFunction = (function() {
      var bigVar = "1234567890";
      return function() {
        alert("Hi there");
        var keepBigVar = bigVar;
      }
    }());
```

Comment: According to [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Closures) which says "Closures are functions that refer to independent (free) variables." my snippets are not closures because they are using anonymous functions as argument variable, am I right?

Comment: Closures have to capture something from an outer scope "close over" that scope and hang onto it.  Like in the example above, `keepBigVar` forms a closure because it hangs onto `bigVar` from the outer scope.  "leakingFunction" executes and finishes -- it is gone -- but `BigVar` lives on.

Comment: just for making sure; `function foo(obj)
{
    $('#something').click(function() { var keepObj = obj; } );
}` does this cause a leak?

Comment: `obj` is caught in a closure, but unless you are calling `foo` multiple times, then it isn't a leak.

Answer (score 3):

Old question, but I have a couple of issues with the top-rated answer -

> By the way, none of the code you are showing uses closures

The click handler in snippet one is very much a closure - it closes over the obj parameter that is passed to foo. Thus, the memory allocated for obj will not be released until foo is called again with a different object.

Not saying there's a leak here - just wanted to point out that snippet one does create a closure.

Also,

> Leaks are held by not releasing memory -- everything there gets released

This is true for snippets #2 and #3, but not for snippet #1.